# business logic and validation in model

Tags: php, validation, oop, model, domain-driven-design

I've a problem with the following situation. I've got an Article entity:

```
class Article {
    private $publishDate;

    public function updatePublishDate(DateTime $date = null) {
        $this->publishDate = $date;
    }
}
```

I would like to apply some business rules for updating the date, such as:
- update the date only when its not already published
- refuse to set the date to the past (must be valid publish date)

Because there is some logic in generating the publishing date, I would like to have separate class for this, because I know it would change:

```
class PublishService {
    public function generatePublishDate() {
        return new DateTime('tomorrow');
    }
}
```

The question is: Where should the validation be? Should I have validation in the entity:

```
...
    public function updatePublishDate(DateTime $date, PublishService $service) {
        if ($date 
            && $this->datePublish > new DateTime
            && $date >= $service->generatePublishDate()) {
            $this->datePublish = $date;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Something wrong with the date...');
        }
    }
...
```

Or should I create a separate ArticleService, that would handle this logic?

What came to my mind:

- validation in entity is fine, because nobody is able to set the wrong publish date in the code (eg. another member of the team, that would have known about ArticleService)
- entity is all the time in valid state
- on the other hand I don't like the method signature :-)

Comment: Why do you have to validate a value that was already generated by some domain logic? What's the business case to update the publish date? When does that occur?

Comment: Use case: when article is already published, you're not able to change it. When it's not already published, but has been set for publishing in the future, you're free to change the publish date.

Comment: I do not get why you have to pass a `$date` and a `PublishService` if `PublishService` generates the next valid date?  Anyway, if you really want to extract your date generation logic, there's nothing wrong in injecting something at the method level. Have you also thought about using a value object rather than a primitive DateTime? That could open up different possibilities.

Comment: User can propose, when the article should be published, if its not already "online". Because there is some article planning, he's a bit limited in his decision. So the PublishService calculates first possible publish date. And to have a valid entity (from the business logic point of view) I need to check if the date proposed by the user is greater or equal to the date provided by PublishService. I hope I've cleared it a bit.

Comment: What are the possibilities with a value object instead of DateTime?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "**User can propose, when the article should be published**, if its not
> already "online". Because there is some article planning, he's a bit
> limited in his decision. So the PublishService calculates first
> possible publish date. And to have a valid entity (from the business
> logic point of view) I need to check if the date proposed by the user
> is greater or equal to the date provided by PublishService." - kodlik

### A better name?

Well, first of all, DDD is all about reflecting the domain in code. Look at how you described the use case to me (in bold above) and how it actually reflected in your code:

`public function updatePublishDate(DateTime $date, PublishService $service)`

From what I read above, I understand that proposing a publishing date doesn't necessarily involve publishing the article right away.

How about `proposePublishingDate` rather than `updatePublishDate`?

### Injecting services

Now, there's really nothing wrong in injecting a service into an entity at the **method** level, but you should follow the [Interface Segregation Principle (ISP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and be more explicit about the dependency. Therefore, rather than depending on a `PublishService`, you could depend on a `PublishingDateGenerator` interface which implements a `nextPublishDate` method.

I want you to focus more on the principle than the names I chose here, but do not forget that these are part of your domain model and should be part of your ubiquitous language.

### The [Tell Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle

From what I can see, you seem to be extracting a date from your `PublishService` only in order to compare it with the date the user proposed.

Rather than asking the `PublishService` for the date and use the date to execute some business logic, why don't you make that rule an explicit concept of your domain by having a `PublishingDatePolicy` instead?

*The following is pseudo-code:*

```
public proposePublishingDate(DateTime date, PublishingDatePolicy policy) {
    if (this.isPublished()) throw ...;
    if (!policy.isSatisfiedBy(date)) throw ...;
    
    this.proposedPublishingDate = date;
}
```

*Note: Policies are discussed in Evans book and are a mean to make business rules explicit. They are pretty much the same as strategies in the Strategy Pattern.*

#### Logic embedded into entity

You might see this as a violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), but I guess it's not always worth to extract simple logic out of the entity to which it is closely related. However, if you expect the rule to change very often it might be a good idea...

### Conclusion

It's hard to tell what's best and whenever you ask a DDD question, you will always get the same answer: "It depends on your domain.". Therefore, you should pick the approach that better aligns with the domain and can be easily expressed as domain concepts defined by the ubiquitous language.

Comment: @MikeSW Mind to review this answer and comment? What do you think of the value object approach?

Comment: Yes, it seems that better names are needed. It seems that your proposal of creating a policy is the way. I hope I get it correctly - I would also inject the policy to my `SomeServiceThatGeneratesPublishDate` and apply the policy to generated date. This way I know that all the generated dates are valid, right?

Comment: @kodlik No, you know that the generated date is valid so that's not what we are trying to validate. We are trying to free the entity from knowing how to use the generated date to validate the user's proposed publishing date. If we want to be inline with your choice of extracting the next publishing date generation from the entity because the strategy might change a lot then the rules revolving around such as validating the user's provided date against the generated date might often change just as well...

Comment: If those other rules do not change often (e.g. the date will always have to be >= generated date) then the policy extraction might not be worth, but you should still use the ISP principle in my opinion like I said in "Injecting services". However, another question you have to ask is "is the generated date only used to validate the user's provided date?". If the answer is true, then you could perhaps encapsulate the whole date generation process and the rule checking within a Policy object that would be passed to the `proposePublishingDate` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Article class you defined intends to model a published or not published article (both representations using the same abstraction). 
Let's think a little bit about the method "updatePublishDate" you wrote for the Article class. Should an article that is already published receive a message (method call) "updatePublishDate"? It is weird: an article that is already published should never have in its protocol a message that opens for everyone the change to tell it: "ey published article, change your publication date to...". So it is a smell design. Now at first sight we can see we need one representation for an article that is published and another representation for an article that is in draft.
So you will have two aggregates with its repos:

```
DraftArticle > DraftArticleRepository
Article > ArticleRepository
```

Whenever you want to publish an article you will pick up a draft article, create an article and move it to the article repository:

```
Publisher.publishArticle(anId) {
   draftArticle = draftArticleRepository.get(andId);
   article = new Article(draftArticle.text());
   articleRepository.add(article);
}
```

The Article gets the current system date as publication date. On the other hand a draft article does not know about publication dates. However, you could have dateToBePublished on a draft article and have a background thread to run daily and publish draft articles matching the time criteria.

Hope it helps.

Comment: From what I could understand, I think that his `publishDate` is actually a `dateToBePublished` concept and it's not actually publishing the article. I like your segregation of the `DraftArticle` and `Article` concepts, but not your implementation. I would rather have a factory method on `DraftArticle` for the `Article` instance, such as `article = draftArticle.publish()`. Also, if having a publishing date is the only thing that actually differs from a normal article, I'm not sure if it wouldn't just be better to have a status field.

Comment: Instead of saying "if having a publishing date is the only thing that actually differs from a normal article, I'm not sure if it wouldn't just be better to have a status field"... if we focus on the object protocol instead of thinking in internal state we would note that a DraftArticle lets an object to change the publication date (changePublicationDate) while an Article does not have that method in its protocol, that's a HUGE difference and I do see necessary to have both representations.

Comment: The thing I'm not sure of now is that clients now also have to know the state of the Article they are looking for since they come from two different repositories. You could have a service method that abstracts that away by issuing a query to both repositories, but that would be odd. I like the conceptual idea but I am not sure if it's actually practical, unless perhaps both classes lives in two different bounded contexts?

Comment: Clients now deal with two different concepts. They can view draft articles (by calling a service that gets the draft articles from a repository) and they could decide to publish them (by placing them into the other repository). It is the same bounded context.